# Riemann-sum -> limit vs factorial/n-th root

Tags: limits, riemann-sum

I'm supposed to find the limit of 
$\lim_{k\to \infty } \frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{\frac{(2n)!}{n!}}$.
By using $e^{\ln }$ and logarithm-laws I managed to form it into
$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt[n]{k+n}$
or

$e^{(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln (k+n))-\ln (n)} $

Not sure where to go from here, appreciate all the help

Comment: $\ln(k + n) - \ln n = \ln(1 + k/n)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\begin{eqnarray}
\log\left(\frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{\frac{(2n)!}{n!}}\right)&=&\log\left(\frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{(n+1)(n+2)...(n+n)}\right)\\
&=&\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\log(k+n)\right)-\log(n)\\
&=&\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\log(k+n)\right)-\frac{n}{n}\log(n)\\
&=&\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\log(k+n)-\log(n)\right)\\
&=&\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)\\
&\to&\int_0^1\log(x+1)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=&\log4-1\\
&=&\log(4/e)
\end{eqnarray}$

Then $\frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{\frac{(2n)!}{n!}}=\exp(\log\left(\frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{\frac{(2n)!}{n!}}\right))\to e^{\log(4/e)}=4/e$